# Can a program wake the computer from Hibernate (S4)?

Tags: windows, hibernate

I'm researching a feature that's supposed to wake up the computer from sleep in order to perform some work. It's a Windows application and I'm still unsure if the "wake timers" from Power Management will only wake the computer from S1-S3 or also S4. Event the MS docs are not so clear on this.

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/system-sleeping-states in reference to Hibernation

> Hardware latency
>
> Long and undefined. **Only physical** interaction returns the system to
> the working state. Such interaction might include the user pressing
> the ON switch or, if the appropriate hardware is present and wake-up
> is enabled, an incoming ring for the modem or activity on a LAN. The
> machine can also awaken from a **resume timer** if the hardware supports
> it.

Is this "resume timer" the same that an app would use to wake the computer from S1-S3? Or is it something else that's supposed to be implemented by the UEFI and is completely independent from Windows?

Comment: My guess is its the same as configuring your bios to power on a system at a given time of day (provided its firmware/hardware supports such an operation). the power state doesn't matter much whether its S4 or just plain off.

Comment: Try https://lifsoft.com/power/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The "resume timer" as mentioned is a BIOS option commonly referred to in BIOS verbiage as an RTC (real-time clock) alarm. This is capable of waking a system from S5.

As for your question, 'is this the same process that an app would use': this is unlikely, as RTC alarms are set in the BIOS, which is prior to OS boot. Yes, these alarms are independent of the OS.

More commonly, Wake-on-LAN (also called "Magic Packet") is able to resume system functionality from all power states to S5, but must be enabled in the NIC settings and BIOS.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock_alarm

This article explains it fairly succinctly and also links to similar features such as WOL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).